# I'm trying to runa code for facial recognition and getting the following error

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to run the follwing code for facial recognition:

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

def detect(gray, frame):
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w,y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale((roi_gray, 1.1, 3))
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex+ew,ey+eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    return frame

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while True:
    _,frame = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    canvas = detect(gray, frame)
    cv2.imshow('Video', canvas)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and it is giving the following error:
OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: There are tons of questions regarding this exact issue. Instead of `_, frame = video_capture.read()` use `ret, frame = video_capture.read()` and check `ret`. Alternatively, check `frame != None` before further processing.

Comment: when I use print(frame.shape) I get: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: and when used the following code:  `print(video_capture.isOpened())`                
`print(video_capture.read())`, i got (false) and (false,none ) as output

Comment: So, obviously your camera connection is not properly set up (or the camera is not connected, or, or, or ...). To avoid errors in your current code coming from that issue, do what I said: Put everything related to `frame` after some `if frame is not None:`.